# When focus is set for input element, the cursor happens to set to start of the string in FF

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, input, mouseevent

I somehow ended up having a SharePoint dialog pop up with input fields. When I click on the  input, it was not getting focused. Therefore I cracked it with below code:

```
$('input').click(function () {
    this.focus();
});
```

Now my problem is, when I get focus, the cursor is set to start of the string in the input field and my next mouse click doesn't work. How to make it behave normally, so that when ever I click the cursor should set to that particular position (first, between or end of the string). Like the default behavior of the input field events.

Comment: without this click handler also your input field gets focus when you click on the input field. why do you want to have this?

Comment: For some reason, it was not working. So I had to include that snippet in my code to work in FF. Note: I am facing this issue only in FF. Has it got something to do with the Sharepoint Dialog UI and FF, where its detaching the events from the input in the DOM???? Also observed that ctrl+A doesnot work either in IE.